# using forloop in switch statement using c#

Tags: c#, foreach, switch-statement

I want to use for loop with switch statement but getting this error: "for each statement cannot operate on variable of type int"

```
 DataRow row = MyData.Rows[0];
   int temp = Convert.ToInt32(row["Category"]);

foreach (int v in temp)
{
                switch (temp)
                {
                    case "1":
                        lblCategory.Text = temp + " - Complete.";
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        lblCategory.Text = temp + " - Not Complete";
                        break;
               }
}
```

okay, i am updating my code based on your feedback but have one last question, i have column called Category in my data collection and it has values like 1,2,3 etc so that is why i mean when i say case "1":

```
var temp = MyData.Rows;
foreach (int v in temp)
{
    switch (v.Category)
    {
    case "1":
        lblCategory.Text += v + " - Complete.\n";
        break;
    case "2":
        lblCategory.Text += v + " - Not Complete\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `foreach (int v in temp)` means? `temp` is not a list. You must have meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
foreach (DataRow row in MyData.Rows)
{
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(row["Category"]);
    switch (v)
    {
    case 1:
        lblCategory.Text += v + " - Complete.\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        lblCategory.Text += v + " - Not Complete\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

In your code sample, you are iterating items in the collection, but switching on the collection itself. Also you are converting an item to an `Int32` but using strings in the case statement.

Comment: thanks, please look at my initial post i just updated the code and missing one little thing

Comment: @moe `Category` is not a property of `v`. I think my code above will do the job for you, e.g.: `Convert.ToInt32(row["Category"])` retrieves the category.

Comment: @moe my code had a problem that didn't define `v` properly, it's now updated.

Comment: Sina, i don't see where you define v in your updated code, i gett error message where it says v does not exist

Answer (score 6):

You need to have a collection of rows to loop through. You wrote a loop for a single element.

For the following line to work:

```
foreach (int v in temp) ...
```

your `temp` variable must be a collection of integers (for example `IEnumerable<int>` or `List<int>` or `int[]`).

Try writing:

```
var temp = MyData.Rows;
```

instead of

```
DataRow row = MyData.Rows[0];
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(row["Category"]);
```

before your `foreach` loop, like so:

```
var temp = MyData.Rows;
foreach (int v in temp)
{
    switch (v)
    {
    case 1:
        lblCategory.Text += v + " - Complete.\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        lblCategory.Text += v + " - Not Complete\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how would i access the Category column because that is the column that has the category number like 1, 2 etc.  I thought i could say: switch (v.Category) { case "1": lblCategory.Text += v + " - Complete.\n";

Comment: Igor Sevo, please look at my initial post, i just updated the code based on your code

Answer (score 1):

From [`foreach, in (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element in an array or an object collection that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface. The foreach
>   statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the
>   information that you want..

But in your code `temp` is an `int`, `Int32` doesn't implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` and it is not a collection at all, so..

Answer (score 0):

switch(v) instead of temp....

also 
your temp variable must be a collection of int

```
DataRow row = MyData.Rows[0];
 int temp = Convert.ToInt32(row["Category"]);

foreach (int v in temp)
{
            switch (v)
            {
                case 1:
                    lblCategory.Text = temp + " - Complete.";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    lblCategory.Text = temp + " - Not Complete";
                    break;
           }
}
```